# Android: Get bitmap/drawable from HTTPS

Tags: android, facebook, https, bitmap, facebook-android-sdk

I want to get an image from a server (HTTPS) and show it in an ImageView.

Images are from Facebook Events (example: https://fbcdn-photos-f-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-prn1/c17.0.50.50/1016204_538791999501573_1791760778_t.jpg )

```
 Drawable.createFromStream((InputStream)new URL("https://fbcdn-photos-f-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-prn1/c17.0.50.50/1016204_538791999501573_1791760778_t.jpg").getContent(), "src");
```

throws NullPointer Exception

Or maybe is there any way to get the image via Facebook SDK?
In Facebook SDK I only know the ProfilePictureView (which may only be for profile pictures???)

Thanks so far!

Comment: Have you tried what we post?

Comment: But everything ends in the same: NullPointerException

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm such a dumbass :D

Everything of your answers were right!!!

I displayed the ImageView in a dialog.

I used the following to point to the ImageView

```
ImageView image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView_event_picture);
```

but for sure this is NULL in a dialog!

It has to be

```
( final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(EventActivity.this); )

ImageView image = (ImageView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.imageView_event_picture);
```

I didn't mention that I'm running it out of a dialog - Sorry!!

Answer (score 0):

have You check internet permission?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

**or** user LazyLoading. so you can have cache stored in sdcard and next time you can get image quickly. so use example of this 
http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-loading-image-from-url-http/

**or** use another method

```
public static Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String src) {
    try {
        Log.e("src",src);
        URL url = new URL(src);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.connect();
        InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
        Log.e("Bitmap","returned");
        return myBitmap;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e("Exception",e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes internet permission is included into AndroidManifest

Comment: follow this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4945115/set-url-image-to-image-view

Answer (score 0):

Check `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`

And I recommend look his:
[Android - Loading Image Url and Displaying in ImageView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16055375/android-loading-image-url-and-displaying-in-imageview/16055761#16055761)

Answer (score 0):

**i recommend you to implement this into your project. It's the best solution.**
https://github.com/thest1/LazyList

Comment: NullPointer Exception: 07-16 10:24:20.535: E/AndroidRuntime(1358):  at com.fedorvlasov.lazylist.ImageLoader$BitmapDisplayer.run(ImageLoader.java:178)



what am I doing wrong? >_<

Comment: Line 178 in ImageLoader.java:                 photoToLoad.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

Comment: what's the constructor you have used? in my case i used this :
 public ImageLoader imageLoader;
  imageLoader = new ImageLoader(context.getApplicationContext());
  imageLoader.DisplayImage(BeanClass.get(position).imageurl, phonepic);

Comment: where's beanClass.get(position).imageurl is the link to the image and phonepic the name of imageview :)

Comment: Used the following constructor: 

ImageLoader imageLoader=new ImageLoader(EventActivity.this);
imageLoader.DisplayImage("http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/548410609/icon_8_73.png", image);

Comment: where image is the ImageView ;-)

Btw: Why there is ";," displayed after the .png"? If I click edit, it's not shown there :o)

Comment: try to add http in android codes. - http:// + + a3.twimg.com/profile_images/548410609/icon_8_73.png

Comment: For sure the image is available :P - by the way: the http:// is just cut out by stackoverflow..

Comment: No still get NullPointerException :(

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33539/discussion-between-xbjoernx-and-kingomar)